# SQL server compact 3.5 namespace not found

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, sql-server-ce

I want to use SQL server compact 3.5, but intellisense is not showing  `System.Data.SqlServerCe` namespace.. it says `type or namespace 'SqlServerCe' does not exist in 'System.Data' namespace (are you missing any Assembly reference?)`

Which Assembly needs to be referenced?

or do I need to use any other namespace to use SQL Server Compact 3.5?

I have Sql Server 2005 Standard and Express installed, and VC# 2010.

Please provide some reference link to work with SQL Server CE 3.5..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `Add Reference`, if you do not see the reference as in the screenshot, browse to the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\Desktop` folder

Comment: +1 your blog is a great (correction: indispensable!) SQL Server CE resource - great stuff, great tools too! THanks.

Comment: Thanks Marc, let me know if you miss anything!

Answer (score 3):

The SQL Server **Compact Edition** (CE) libraries live in the `System.Data.SqlServerCe` namespace, which is in the `System.Data.SqlServerCe` assembly. This assembly is not referenced by default - you need to explicitly add a reference to it before you can use it!

[image]

Once you have that in place, you will also need a

```
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
```

at the top of your C# file using SQL Server CE.

Check out [Erik EJ's blog](http://erikej.blogspot.com/2009/04/sql-compact-3rd-party-tools.html) for a great reference for all things SQL Server CE

Comment: I don't find that reference under .NET References list. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a reference to the 'System.Data.SqlServerCe' assembly. You can download and install CE from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=7400).