# 'New' cannot be used on an interface

Tags: vb.net, interface, ado.net, instance, idbconnection

I am just learning to use Dapper for an SQL CE database.

I have typed the following code to open a connection:

```
    Dim con As IDbConnection
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=D:\test.sdf"
    con.Open()
```

VS underlines the "con" in the line "con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=D:\test.sdf" and tells me:
Variable 'con' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception might occur.

To get rid of this comment, I have tried

```
Dim con As new IDbConnection
```

But that did not compile: 'New' cannot be used on an interface.

How do I deal with this?

Edit:

I have now tried the following:

```
    Dim nStrongType As System.Data.Common.DbConnection()

    Dim con As IDbConnection
    con = nStrongType
```

That did not work. The compiler told me:

DBConnection cannot be converted to IDBConnection.

Thank you!

Comment: You would create an instance of an object that implements IDbConnection, Perhaps Dim con As new DbConnection (DBConnection implements IDbConnection).

Comment: I'm truly shocked that someone who has been programming long enough to amass 10,000 rep points here doesn't understand such fundamental concepts. If you expect to set a property of an object then you have to have an object, so it should be obvious why the first code snippet doesn't work. As for the second issue, if you don't understand how interfaces work then you should stop what you're doing and learn about that now. All ADO.NET providers implement standard interfaces, so they all work basically the same way. If you're connecting to SQLite then you'd probably need a `SqliteConnection`.

Comment: @Hursey Do you mean like that? Dim con As New System.Data.Common.DbConnection? I am asking because it says "Cannot use New on a class that is declared 'MustInherit'.

Comment: @John I am connecting to a SQL Server Compact file. I have read about Interface a few times because I thought I could perhaps use it, but I have never needed it myself, so I forgot about it again and how to implement / use it.

Comment: @John I have edited my post according to what I think would be correct, but it won't work.

Comment: Hi. You can't have `ISomething` instances, you can have instances of a class that implements that interface `Class Something Implements ISomething End Class`. As for the SQL CE, you need to use the `System.Data.SqlServerCe` classes. If you don't have it, [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact/#readme-body-tab) it. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874361/sql-server-compact-3-5-namespace-not-found). Consider the `SQLite` db instead.

Comment: See also https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-compact/

Comment: @dr.null Thank you. I love SQLite, but in this case, it's not my app, and I have to use the existing SQL CE database.

Comment: @dr.null Thank you very much! Downloading System.Data.SqlServerCe is the best solution! I didn't write than anywhere else. Thank you for telling me about it.